# Add time to the date value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I am using a `jQuery` plugin named `mobiscroll` to select a date, but the problem is that I also need to add to the result plus 15 minutes.

I have a function `p(j)`, which returns `08/28/2012 12:15 - 12:15` (or only `08/28/2012 12:15` - as convenient), but instead i need `12:15 - 12:30`. Are there any ideas?

Comment: @Sirko there only compressed jquery, so need to do some thing with this string

Comment: `08/28/2012 12:15 - 12:15` it is a string or a date object ?

Comment: @Genosite i think it is a string.

Comment: can you check the type with `typeof` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mobiscroll [documentation](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/datetime-preset) setDate works with a Date object.

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) on how to work with date objects in javascript. You don't need to do any string manipulations.

After you have the right date use the `.scroller('setDate',newDate,true);`

Answer (score 1):

What about string manipulation?

```
var dateStr = p(j), //08/28/2012 12:15 - 12:15
    timeStrSlice = dateStr.split(' ')[1].split(':'),
    h = parseFloat(timeStrSlice[0]),
    m = parseFloat(timeStrSlice[1]);

var nh = h,
    nm = m + 15;

if(nm > 60) {
   nh++;
   nm = 0;
}
if(nh > 24) {
   nh = 0;
}

var result = h + ":" + m + " " + nh + ":" + nm; // 12:15 12:30
```

Comment: Your code can't work look line 7 : `nm = m + 15` nm is not reset

Comment: What do you mean its not reset? have you noticed `,` (comma) sign at the end of line 6?

Comment: if `m = 60` with `nm = m + 15` nm = 75 so `nm > 60` its impossible

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. I added `nm = 0` line after increasing `nh`.

Answer (score 0):

Date d = new Date(2012,08,28); 
d.setHours(12, 30, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
var now = new Date();
//add 15 minutes to now
var out = new Date(now).setMinutes(now.getMinutes()+15)
```